# R kableExtra two center alignments: one for columns with linebreaks and another for others

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kableextra

**Output Desired**

Using R `kableExtra`, I want to create the following table formatting in both PDF and HTML  output (at least the newline, centering and LaTeX equations are present) like the following.
[image]

**The Code Attempt**

The following R code renders the desired PDF output correctly:

```r
#-------------------
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
#-------------------

fs_dt <- tibble(
  school = 1:4,
  nstudents = c(1471,890,1021,1587),
  nf_total = c(792,447,511,800),
  nf_intv = c(25,15,20,40),
  nsmokers = c(10,3,6,27)
)

fs_dt %>% 
 kbl(booktabs = T,
    col.names = linebreak(c("School",
                  "No. of students",
                  "No. of females\n($M_i$)",
                  "No. of females interviewed\n($m_i$)",
                  "$\\sum_{i\\in\\mathcal{S}} y_{ij}$"),
                  align = "c"),
    escape = FALSE,
    align = "ccccc"
    ) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped","hold_position"))
```

However, the HTML output looks like the following where the third and fourth column names are missing.

[image]

**The Question**

How can we achieve both output using a single code without resorting to conditional coding (e.g., `is_html_output()`/`is_latex_output()`)?

Comment: `huxtable` interprets newlines, if that alternative would be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is a little problem.**

Library `kableExtra` doesn't work with  `\n` in "HTML-mode".

**What do you can to do?**

1. You can change `\n` to `<br>` when knitting to HTML.
2. It isn't conveniently, especially, when you have a lot of tables (changing `\n` to `<br>` every time.

   For this case you can use `column_spec`:

   ```
   #your code above
   escape = FALSE,
   align = "ccccc"
   ) %>% 
   column_spec(3, width = "3cm") %>%
   column_spec(4, width = "5.3cm") %>% #4.8 cm for PDF!!!
   kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped","hold_position"))
   ```

   You should determinate your width every time (sometimes for the every output), it is a little tedious.

   Every solution have some underwater rocks, so we must fight with compromises :(

[image]